# The body of literature, and more generally media, pertaining to some topic

Tags: single-word-requests

Sort of like "canon" but without the implication of being formally authorized by any body - the word I am looking for could conceivably include fan fiction as well.

E.g. "The creature name I am looking for is not 'flesh atronach', because that name is specific to the Elder Scrolls _____."

I thought there was such a word.

Comment: How about "corpus"?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [**lore**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/lore):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> 3 : a particular body of knowledge or tradition · the *lore* of baseball heroes

From an older article called ["Star Wars Lore Is Changing—Here's What That Means"](https://kotaku.com/star-wars-lore-is-changing-heres-what-that-means-1568713480) (bold text mine):

> But Disney and LucasFilm are producing new *Star Wars* movies set after the original trilogy, and they've decided that the task of reconciling the stories in these new films with the incredibly dense Expanded Universe **lore** is an impossible one. . . .
>
> Kyle Katarn, for example, is the lead character in three of the four *Jedi Knight* games. While he does show up in some novels, his adventures in those games never feel like they exist in the same timeline as the rest of **the lore**, and are never (as far as I can recall) referenced in other works, just as those games never reference what else is going on in the galaxy at the time. The expansion pack to *Jedi Knight, Mysteries of the Sith*, even stars Mara Jade, and it exists in that same almost context-free bubble.

And an article called ["Lord of the Rings - Lore beyond the films for the non-hardcore fans"](https://steemit.com/steemit/@silent.screamer/lord-of-the-rings-lore-beyond-the-films-for-the-non-hardcore-fans) (bold text mine):

> We all know Peter Jackson's epic Lord of the rings [*sic*] film trilogy and The Hobbit trilogy; we were immersed into Middle Earth **lore** and the epic battles that we saw on the movies (Ride of the Rohirim!).